# how to show icon based on file type with avoid number of ngIf condition?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to have check ngIf on common module? 
My problem is we have lot of file type, So that i want avoiding *ngIf condition each file type

,

Comment: <img *ngIf="filetype == png" src="image.png" /> <img *ngIf="filetype == pdf" src="pdf.png" />,

<img *ngIf="filetype == png" src="image.png" /> <img *ngIf="filetype == pdf" src="pdf.png" />,

Comment: Why not just use icon names based on the file extensions? Then you can simply use the file extension name e.g.: png/pdf/jpg/txt/docx/php etc.... and simply add the image extension to it so you will get png.png/pdf.png/jpg.png/docx.png/js.png etc...
But you should also be able to fetch the mimetype of the file for which you want to show an icon for so you should't be needing all those ngif statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a map inside of your component class, it will look like:

```
this.filesByFiletype = {
  png: 'image.png',
  pdf: 'pdf.png' 
}
```

And in the template use it like this:

```
<img [src]="filesByFiletype[filetype]" />
```